# SQL Server view issue

Tags: sql-server

I've ran the select query on a view to check it's count. but the select statement is running continuously and no result set is coming. I've verified deadlocks and locks on tables etc.. and refreshed the view. But no use.

```
select count(*) from My_View
```

Any suggestions for me

Answer (score 0):

You would require to share what query you are running but before that you should try checking deeper as view might communicating to multiple tables and one of them or many might be creating lock.
You can give a try something like this

```
SELECT row_count = SUM(row_count)
  FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('your_view')
  AND index_id IN (0,1);
```

Comment: i'm using select count(*) from <<view name>>

Comment: Result set is NULL after executing the query shared by you @learner

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQ-LINE dynamic to take more indexes:

declare @Query nvarchar(max)=''

```
set @Query='
                SELECT MessageTotalCount = SUM(st.row_count),getdate() as LastDate
                FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
                WHERE object_name(object_id) ='+ char(39)+'your view'+CHAR(39)+'AND (index_id < 2)
           '

    EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: result is NULL. now i'm verifying the join conditions in my view again.